# How to load different size of image from sdcard android?

Tags: android

I want load 4mb,19mb,3mb size images from sd card into image view.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
 InputStream inputStream=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
 options.inSampleSize=2;
 options.inJustDecodeBounds=false;
 Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName,options);
```

when i use this code, i can't get exact size for all images. Based on the screen capablity the images should be load. If a screen have the capablity to load 19mb image that time i don't want to use option.insampleSize=2. If it doesn't have that, that time only i want to decrease the size of image only for that 18Mb and other images i don't want to do like that.

Comment: You can put your images in drawable folders LDPI , HDPI , MDPI etc for different screen sizes.

Comment: You shouldnt be loading anything in full resolution unless its smaller than screen size.

Comment: ali imran. i am loading those bitmaps from remotepath

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
int sampleSize = 1;

while (true) {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName,options);

        // some code here

        break;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
        sampleSize++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dinamically request size of the screen

```
int screenSize = (resources.getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK);
DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
```

And then use

```
metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels
```

or

```
if (screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) // or another constant screen sizes in Configuration class.
```

And request image size without loading the whole image using image's URI:

```
InputStream input = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
input.close();
int originalHeight = onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight; 
int originalWidth = onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;
```

And then choose inSampleSize in runtime.

Comment: if some image have small size(2MB) with big resolution(1024*1024) that time it is not necessary. we have to load full image with exact resolution of that image if the image has small size.

Comment: You can get byte array from URI with     InputStream iStream =   getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream); and know size of the bitmap and then choose inSampleSize

Comment: poM6oH. how can i find the maximum size can be load in a screen?

Comment: metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels give you width and height of the screen in pixels.